# imgAreaSelect .update() within onSelectEnd event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using [`imgAreaSelect`](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/), I'm trying to set a default selection if the user selects an area that is too small (a simple click). I'm however unable to call `.update()` within `onSelectEnd`.. I feel like I'm missing something but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#crop-large').on('open.leanModal', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            selectlarge = $('.img-orig-large').imgAreaSelect({
                instance: true,
                handles: true,
                zIndex: 12000,
                imageWidth: <?php echo $imgsize[0]; ?>,
                imageHeight: <?php echo $imgsize[1]; ?>,
                onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
                    if(selection.width > 20 && selection.height > 20) {
                        $('input[name="large-x1"]').val(selection.x1);
                        $('input[name="large-y1"]').val(selection.y1);
                        $('input[name="large-x2"]').val(selection.x2);
                        $('input[name="large-y2"]').val(selection.y2);
                    } else {
                        truewidth  = <?php echo $imgsize[0]; ?>;
                        trueheight = <?php echo $imgsize[1]; ?>;
                        var dummy_x1 = truewidth*0.25;
                        var dummy_y1 = trueheight*0.25;
                        var dummy_x2 = truewidth*0.75;
                        var dummy_y2 = trueheight*0.75;
                        $('input[name="large-x1"]').val(dummy_x1);
                        $('input[name="large-y1"]').val(dummy_y1);
                        $('input[name="large-x2"]').val(dummy_x2);
                        $('input[name="large-y2"]').val(dummy_y2);
                        selectlarge.setSelection(dummy_x1, dummy_y1, dummy_x2, dummy_y2, true);
                        selectlarge.update();
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 300);
    });
    $('#crop-large').on('close.leanModal', function() {
    }, function() {
        selectlarge.cancelSelection();
    });
});
```

Comment: Closures! Also, just to confirm - is there any errors within the Browser Console? (`F12`). Lastly, please could you provide a small snippet of the HTML for a fiddle?

Comment: No error in the console, and fiddle on the way

Comment: well... I can't figure out how to link both JS files but here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/UY4Sw/1/

Comment: Some changes: http://jsfiddle.net/NAKbj/1/

Comment: prettier code, but I'm wanting to show the select area using the defaultCoords.

Comment: I know! and annoyingly I'm finding it strangely difficult too!

Comment: @veken cracked it! ;)

Comment: I was just looking at all the fun you've had animating it and stuff haha!

Comment: hahaha! yea sorry :P I've actually used this great plugin before on a project at work, and it was really annoying me how this wasn't working! (And indeed, I saw that animating thing, thought it was pretty cool :)!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be a pretty small tweak, you were almost there! You have to *re-set* the `show` option prior to the `.update()` if you want to have the new selection box, visually change:

```
//setOptions with show, sets the gridarea for the next update
selectlarge.setOptions({ show: true });
selectlarge.update();
```

Which then successfully redraws the box upon a single click as like it does within the below Fiddle, which listens to the dimensions which are set within the `defaultCoords` object:

#### Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pg39A/

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going crazy!